ERROR ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined Angular 18
I'm encountering an error in my Angular 18 application related to sessionStorage. My code is throwing a ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined in the MyComponent. Here’s the relevant code snippet where the error occurs:
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const sessionId = sessionStorage.getItem('sessionId'); // Error occurs here
    // Other logic
  }
}

Another interesting part is, I don't get this error when I use sesssionStorage.setitem
export class GenerateInfo {
  public sessionId!: string;

  constructor() { }
   
  setSessionIdToStorage(): void {
        sessionStorage.setItem('sessionId', JSON.stringify(this.sessionId));  // No error here
    // Other logic
  }
}


Try accessing through the window object.
I am also using typescript safe access check ?. to ensure the values are checked at each level of access to prevent errors.
ngOnInit(): void {
    const sessionId = window?.sessionStorage?.getItem('sessionId'); // Error occurs here
    // Other logic
}

